# Why can't I submit my form with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox in Perl?

Tags: html, perl, mechanize

I have an HTML this is part of the form I'm working on

```
<form action="/goform/FormUpdateVAP" autocomplete="off" name="myform" id="formid" method="POST">
<table>
    <tbody>             
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><span class="label">Name:</span></td>
                <td><input id="essid" name="essid"  value="X" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><input id="broadcast_essid" name="broadcast_essid" value="any" checked="" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td><span class="label">Broadcast name:</span></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- BEGIN RIGHT COLUMN -->
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <input name="authentication" id="authentication" value="any" onclick="Update();" type="checkbox"><span class="label"><b>authentication</b></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input onclick="Update();" name="wp" id="wp" value="any" type="checkbox"><span class="label"><b>Wp</b></span>
            <select id="8021x_mode" name="8021x_mode" onchange="Update();"><option value="wpa">WPA</option>
            <option value="wep">WEP</option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="26">&nbsp;
            <input onclick="Update();" name="w_p" id="w_p" value="any" type="checkbox"><span class="label"><b>Wp</b></span>
            <select id="8021x_mode" name="8021x_mode" onchange="Update();"><option value="wpa">WPA</option>
            <option value="wep">WEP</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href = '/fg/list.asp';" type="button">

    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="add-2" name="add" value="Save" type="submit">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to submit it filling the Name and the Broadcast name. And checking the **8021x_mode** and the **wp** checkboxes. If I tick **8021x_mode** and set the fields the form submits just fine. But when I try ticking **wp** it doesn't submit. I got no error messages.
Here's my code so far:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use Crypt::SSLeay;
use URI::Fetch;
use HTML::TagParser;
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0; #not verifying certificate

my $url = 'https://';
$url = $url.@ARGV[0]; 
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new;
$mech->get($url);

$mech->form_id('formid');
$mech->tick( '8021x_mode','any'); 
$mech->tick( 'wp','any'); --after I add this the form doesn't submit
my $name = @ARGV[1];

$mech->set_fields(
    'vap_name' => $name, 
    'essid' => $name,
);
$mech->click_button( id => 'add-2' );
$mech->reload();
```

**add-2** is the submit button. Any idea why is not working? If you need more information please let me now. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: First : **ALWAYS** put `use strict; use warnings;`. Do it and tell us if you have warnings.

Comment: Well I was just doing it and it gave me **Scalar value @ARGV[0] better written as $ARGV[0]** and that for every argument I use. It also gave me the error **Global symbol "$base_href" requires explicit package name** (I was dumping the page). So removed it, but I'd like to know why is that and how to fix it.

Comment: Those warnings are there to help you identify your problem.  So change your `@ARGV[0] to $ARGV[0]` like it says.  As to the code that throws a warning on `$base_href`, that must be some other code because I don't see `$base_href` in this code.

Comment: Also, this is not WWW::Mechanize, but WWW::Mechanize::Firefox which is different.

Comment: I was using $base_href but I remove it, because it wasn't necesary. And yes, sorry, it is WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the html doesn't contains the choice `any` for 8021x_mode.

I get this error :

> No elements found for Checkbox with name '8021x_mode' and value 'any'
>   at test.pl line 24.

To check the form, I recommend you the `mech-dump` utility (installed with `WWW::Mechanize`)

```
$ mech-dump --forms http://domain.tld/path_to_forms
POST /goform/FormUpdateVAP [myform]
  essid=X                        (text)
  broadcast_essid=<UNDEF>        (checkbox) [*<UNDEF>/off|any]
  authentication=<UNDEF>         (checkbox) [*<UNDEF>/off|any/authentication]
  wp=<UNDEF>                     (checkbox) [*<UNDEF>/off|any/Wp]
  8021x_mode=wpa                 (option)   [*wpa/WPA|wep/WEP]
  w_p=<UNDEF>                    (checkbox) [*<UNDEF>/off|any/Wp]
  8021x_mode=wpa                 (option)   [*wpa/WPA|wep/WEP]
  cancel=Cancel                  (button)
  add=Save                       (submit)
```

As you can see, there's no `any` choice...

Maybe the `javascript` there is doing some things that we don't know.

A workaround is to use `LiveHttpHeaders` `Firefox` addon to catch the forms `POST`ed to `/goform/FormUpdateVAP` and then instead of ticking, do a `POST` request with `WWW::Mechanize`.

Comment: @sputnik I did it, but the url is what I'm expecting except that the submit never happens.

Comment: Is the URL public ? If yes, paste it, I will try.